# Rendering primitives through shader on ATI doesn't show

Tags: c++, opengl, nvidia, ati

I am refactoring a physics simulator that previously used opengl 1.1 Now I am setting it up to use VBO's and GLSL shaders. Currently the particles in the simulation are all drawn from a VBO where as the physical boundaries are drawn with the opengl immediate mode. (I know immediate mode isn't an end solution but upgrading it is for another time)

**The Problem:**
After testing I have discovered that on ATI cards the boundaries are not being drawn. I set up a simple test project to figure out what is going on and I see the same results as my main project:

I can draw the VBO object, the Buddha, in this case, and when I disable the shaders I can draw in immediate mode. But when I try to use immediate mode to put the triangles in '3d' space it won't render on just the ATI.

ATI rendering
http://s23.postimg.org/xcgjxl2h7/ATI.png

Nvidia rendering
http://s23.postimg.org/qaimbdyvf/NVIDIA.png

So the white triangle is when I use

```
glUseProgram(0);
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    glVertex3f(-0.9, 1, -1.0);
    glVertex3f(-0.9, -1, -1.0);
    glVertex3f(-0.2, 1, -1.0);
glEnd();
```

The red triangle is

```
glUseProgram(shaderProgramPrimID);
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    glVertex3f(0.9, 1, -1.0);
    glVertex3f(0.9, -1, -1.0);
    glVertex3f(0.2, 1, -1.0);
glEnd();
```

And the Buddha is a `glDrawElements` call

Relevant shaders:
VertexShaderPrim

```
#version 130

in vec4 s_vPosition;
in vec4 s_vColor;
out vec4 color;

void main () {
    color = s_vColor;
    gl_Position = s_vPosition;
}
```

FragmentShaderPrim

```
#version 130

in vec4 color;
out vec4 fColor;

void main () {
    fColor = color;
}
```

VertexShader

```
#version 130

in vec4 s_vPosition;    
in vec4 s_vNormal;      

uniform mat4 mM;        
uniform mat4 mV;        
uniform mat4 mP;        
uniform mat4 mRotations;

uniform vec4 vLight;    

out vec3 fN;        
out vec3 fL;        

out vec3 fE;        

void main () {
    fN = (mRotations*s_vNormal).xyz;    
    fL = (vLight).xyz;              
    fE = (mV*mM*s_vPosition).xyz;   
    gl_Position = mP*mV*mM*s_vPosition;
}
```

FragmentShader

```
#version 130

in vec3 fN;
in vec3 fL;
in vec3 fE;     

out vec4 fColor;

void main () {
    vec3 N = normalize(fN);
    vec3 L = normalize(fL);

    vec3 E = normalize(-fE);
    vec3 H = normalize(L + E);      

    float diffuse_intensity = max(dot(N, L), 0.0);
    vec4 diffuse_final = diffuse_intensity*vec4(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 1.0);

    float spec_intensity = pow(max(dot(N, H), 0.0), 30);
    vec4 spec_final = spec_intensity*vec4(0.9, 0.1, 0.1, 1.0);

    fColor = diffuse_final + spec_final;
}
```

Comment: A couple of observations from a quick look: The white triangle is counter-clockwise, while the red triangle is clockwise. If you have backface culling enabled, the red triangle would disappear. But that would happen for both vendors, so that's probably not the issue. The other thing is that you use -1.0 for the z-coordinates of your triangles. That's exactly on the boundary of the view volume. Not sure if the clipping behavior is defined if something is exactly on the boundary. Just as an experiment, can you try something like -0.99 for the z coordinates?

Comment: I changed the coordinates, but no change, still shows on nvidia and not ATI. I disabled the backface culling so that's why they still show up

Comment: I think I have a more viable theory. In your shader, you're using generic vertex attributes. But your code uses `glVertex3f` for the red triangle, which sets a pre-defined attribute. And I don't see it setting a color at all. To make this all perfectly clean, you need to get/set the attribute locations of your shader program (for example set the location of `s_vPosition` to 0 and `s_vColor` to 1 before linking, using `glBindAttribLocation`). Then in the drawing code, use `glVertexAttrib3f(1, ...)` for setting the color and `glVertexAttrib3f(0, ...)` for drawing the vertices.

Comment: Oh well, Andon typed faster. :) The problem sounds familiar, doesn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NVIDIA is known for doing things that it is not supposed to with respect to vertex attributes. In this case, you are taking advantage of vertex attribute aliasing, which actually violates the GLSL spec.

If you are going to used fixed-function vertex attributes, do not write your shader the way you have. Either use `glVertexAttrib* (0, ....)` or use `gl_Vertex` instead of a generic vertex attribute (e.g. `s_vPosition`).

Even though vertex attribute **0** generally aliases to `gl_Vertex`, you are relying on undefined behavior to assign `in s_vPosition` to attribute slot **0**. There simply is no guarantee that this will happen. `s_vColor` could be assigned to **0**, particularly since some GLSL implementations will re-arrange your attribute variables alphabetically before automatically assigning them locations.

The bottom line is you should not be using fixed-function vertex attributes the way you are. I would suggest either using explicit generic attributes and binding the attribute locations in your shader, or simply using `gl_Vertex`, `gl_Color`, etc. instead of generic attributes.

Comment: So, if I understand, in the shader I have in 'vec4 s_vPosition' works with the VBO because I pass in the position in the buffer. But with the immediate mode the shader isn't getting the vertex information correctly as they aren't explicitly passed in?

Comment: @user3565590: It really depends on how you setup your vertex pointers. Chances are you're using `glVertexAttribPointer (...)`. `glVertex3f (...)` is tied to `gl_Vertex` in the vertex shader, but may also alias to generic vertex atribute **0**. The real big problem here is that even if this alias is respected by the implementation, implementations may also assign generic vertex attributes in a vertex shader in any order they want. You would need to use `glBindAttribLocation (...)` and make sure you use `glVertexAttrib3f (0, ...)` instead of `glVertex3f (...)` to do this portably.

Comment: Also as a clarification, the VBO is using 'glVertexAttribPointer(positionID, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);' with the 'positionID' pointing to 's_vPosition' to send the position to the shader, if I am changing the shader to get the vertex info correctly from the boundaries would I need some sort of boolean for VBO ->'gl_Position = mP*mV*mM*s_vPosition;' vs boundary ->'gl_Position = mP*mV*mM*fl_Vertex;'?

Comment: No, if you have queried the `positionID`, that is all you need. Instead of writing `glVertex3f (...)` in your immediate-mode code, replace that with `glVertexAttrib3f (positionID, ...)`. Now, the weird thing about immediate mode, however, is that it only creates a vertex when you send something to generic attribute **0**. Immediate mode is an awful thing, if you can refactor your code to avoid it completely that is your best bet to be honest. Likewise, instead of `glColor3f (...)`, use something like `glVertexAttrib3f (colorID, ...)`.

Comment: Oh, ok, so 'glVertexAttrib3f (0, ...)' the 0 refers to attribute 0 in the shader which is linked to the variable 'gl_Vertex'. But using 'glVertex3f (...)' isn't guaranteed to go anywhere?

Comment: It will go somewhere, it is just that GLSL tries to avoid collisions between fixed-function vertex data (e.g. `glVertex3f (...)`, `glColor3f (...)`) and generic attributes (e.g. **0**, **1**, **2**) by not aliasing them. NVIDIA drivers alias them, but compliant GLSL implementations are supposed to keep them completely separate. That means that `glVertex3f (...)` is not necessarily going to be accessible using anything other than `gl_Vertex` in the vertex shader. It ***might*** alias to generic attribute **0**, but you cannot be sure.

Comment: So I must have missed something, I changed the triangle call to `glVertexAttrib3f(positionID, -10.9, 1, 1.0);` where `positionID` is `s_vPosition` and the final position is given by `gl_Position = mP*mV*mM*s_vPosition;` in vertexShader to get it in 3d. But I feel like the issue is that I haven't set it to the generic attribute 0. It still displays on Nvidia but not the ATI

Comment: Actually, after poking around in code I figured it out, `positionPrimID = glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgramPrimID, "s_vPosition");` and then `glVertexAttrib3f(positionPrimID, 0.2, 1, -0.99);` set it up, thanks for the help!